# Why does this Python code get the name error?

Tags: python, class, nameerror

I want to have attribute that is shared by and accessible to all instances of a class.

Sample code:

```
class Test:

    code = [ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    code2d = [ [ code[j*3 + i] for i in range(3) ] for j in range(3) ]

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

However, I get error:

> NameError: name 'code' is not defined

If I put the lines with `code` and `code2d` into init method, all is working properly.

Why this code throws the error?

Comment: Do you really want code and code2d to be class variables?

Comment: Yes, I need code2d. However this is the sample code, The real one is much more complicated and I need to take advantage of nested list comprehension.

Comment: Why do you need everything? The issue can be reproduced with the above code?

Comment: This is the full code.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the above error on both 2.6.9 and 2.7.6.

Comment: Well, in 2.7 all is working properly. In 3.4 I get this error.

Comment: @AnandSKumar No. I just copied the above code and tried on both iPython and normal Python shell. Works fine for me.

Comment: @ozgur: see the duplicate. List comprehensions in Python 3 have their own namespace and thus the class scope isn't visible. The same error happens when using set or dictionary comprehensions in Python 2, as well as generator expressions.

Comment: thanks @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`code` is a class variable , and hence when accessing it you need to call - `Test.code` , you cannot access them using `code` .

Also, even if you do access them using `Test.code` , it would still not work, because the value for class variables (default value) is calculated when the class is being defined, so when you try to access `Test.code` , you would not be able to access `Test` as it has not been created yet. Example of that -

```
>>> class Test:
...     code = [ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
...     code2d = [ [ Test.code[j*3 + i] for i in range(3) ] for j in range(3) ]
...     def __init__(self):
...         pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in Test
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <listcomp>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <listcomp>
NameError: name 'Test' is not defined
```

I am guessing when you put them in the `__init__()` you are putting them as -

class Test:

```
def __init__(self):
    code = [ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    code2d = [ [ code[j*3 + i] for i in range(3) ] for j in range(3) ]
```

This would work, because `code` here is a `local variable` and hence can be accesed by the other local variables in the `__init__()` method , though they would not be accessible outside this function.

---

Maybe, you do not need them as **class variables** , if you want to have `code` and `code2d` for all instances of the class (objects of the class) , you should create instance variable as-

```
>>> class Test:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.code = [ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
...         self.code2d = [ [ self.code[j*3 + i] for i in range(3) ] for j in range(3) ]
```

---

If you really want `code` and `code2d` to be class variables , one way to do it would be to define `code2d` outside the class `Test` , example -

```
class Test:
    code = [ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    def __init__(self):
        pass


Test.code2d = [ [ Test.code[j*3 + i] for i in range(3) ] for j in range(3) ]
```

Comment: *If I put the lines with 'code' and 'code2d' into init method, all is working properly. I don't understand why this code throws the error.* You are not explaining why it doesn't work when trying to use this in the class body; the OP *already knows* it works when you put this in the `__init__` method.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Added that based on a guess, though he didn't put the code for which it was working, so I didn't put that case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I said in the start - `code is a class variable , and hence when accessing it you need to call - Test.code , you cannot access them using code .` , this explains it.

Comment: So why doesn't it work when using that exact code when creating *class attributes*? Hint: see the duplicate.

Comment: Ok, thanks for help. I guess I will define code2d outside the class.